# Whenever I wrap my App with PersistGate it gives me "TypeError: users.map is not a function" in one component, otherwise it works fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

As the title says, I'm mapping through an array I have from an api in UserCardList component and it works fine but once I wrap App with PersistGate, it gives me "TypeError: users.map is not a function" and the error message from redux logger is "redux-persist: persist timed out for persist key "root". I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";

import { store, persistor } from "./redux/store";

import "./index.css";
import "tachyons";
import App from "./containers/App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
```

redux store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import rootReducer from "../redux/root-reducer";

const logger = createLogger();

const middlewares = [logger, thunkMiddleware];

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export default { store, persistor };
```

root-reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

import requestUsers from "./reducers";

const persistConfig = {
    key: "root",
    storage,
    whitelist: ["users"],
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    users: requestUsers,
});

export default persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
```

UserCardList component

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import UserCard from "./UserCard";

const UserCardList = ({ users }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="f1"> Users </h1>
      {users.map((user) => {
        return (
          <UserCard
            key={user.login.uuid}
            image={user.picture.large}
            firstName={user.name.first}
            lastName={user.name.last}
            email={user.email}
            city={user.location.city}
            country={user.location.country}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default UserCardList;
```

Comment: do you get anything in `UserCardList` when `console.log(users)`? Maybe try `users && users.map...` to see if users being set with delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sample project [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-persist-example) by taking the code from your question and everything looks fine for me. And the store is getting created and `users` is coming as expected. 
There could be a possible error in the `reducers` which is not posted here. Please have a look at the sample project, hope it helps.

Comment: I've seen the project and I think it's the same as mine but still the error won't go away. I spent so much time on to be honest. I've created a repo of my project. It's a small one. https://github.com/karimkozman/Random-user-api-app. Would really appreciate if you can help me find what's wrong. Thanks

Comment: Hey I just checked the code and while on debugging I understood that `users` prop in `UserCardList.jsx` has another key named `users` which actually has the data. So in `UserCardList.jsx` file instead of doing `users.map` use `users.users.map`. This should solve the issue

Comment: Thank you! It works now. but I'm a bit confused about the the other key named users which has the data. However the users list changes when I refresh so that means that persist isn't working tho. Do you know why is that?

Comment: As per what I understand from [State Reconciler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist#state-reconciler) docs by default it'll be set to `autoMergeLevel1 ` and if any of the other properties are changes in the reducer they'll get updated, so in your case `isPending` getting updated from `true` to `false` and vice versa. Also, I have checked by debugging it's working fine. If you want to check whether it's working fine or not, once you start the app, comment all the `cases` in `reducers.js` and try reloading the app.

Comment: Also, one more thing that I found which was wrong in the sample app which you shared is that in `HomePage.jsx` while mapping state you were doing this 
`const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    users: state.users,
    isPending: state.isPending,
    error: state.error
  };
};`

Instead you should do like below  
`const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    users: state.users.users,
    isPending: state.users.isPending,
    error: state.users.error
  };
};
`
And use `users.map` in `UserCardList.jsx` instead of `users.users.map`

Comment: I really appreciate your help and effort man! Thank you so much! I just have one last question I promise haha, I had to remove isPending state from the cases in reducers.js as this was making persist not working. Does that mean I can't add another state since they'll get updated? Did I get understand that right? I'm new to redux so I'm still learning.

Comment: No problem at all, Pleasure is all mine :-). Here one thing I want to mention is that Persist is working, And if you want to store only the user's data not anything else that can also be achieved even if there are other state variables as well. That can be achieved using [Nested Persists](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist#nested-persists) approach. 
Also it's expected that if there's any change in other state variables then the persist storage should get updated and will get updated for that particular state not everything else. In you case only `isPending` will get updated.

Comment: I faced this weird problem. I tried to clear browser's local storage with ```localStorage.clear()``` and now there's no list of users. It looks like the PersistStore works, when I already retrieved and persisted users once. So users are being loaded but not stored. Do you have an idea how can I solve this problem? sorry for asking too many questions.

Comment: It's okay, not a problem at all :-). By default `redux-persist` use `localStorage` for web. So it's expected that when you call `localStorage.clear()` will clear the list of users which was being stored. 
But I didn't quite understand what's the problem that you are facing. Sorry can you please explain.

Comment: I mean is there another way to store the users so that when I call ```localStorage.clear()``` they would still be there?

Comment: If you've to do `localStorage.clear()` and still you want to persists the data, what I can think of is that change the storage type of `redux-persist` to `sessionStorage` like `import storageSession from 'redux-persist/lib/storage/session'` in `root-reducer` and use in the `persistConfig`. Having said that there are some limitations of using `sessionStorage` compared to `localStorage`. There are several other Storage Engines available, please have a look over [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist#storage-engines)

Comment: Honestly man, I don't know what to say but you are the best! I wish more people are patient and helpful as you are :) Thank you once again!

Comment: Thanks you :-). That means a lot. I'm not doing anything great, just trying to help with what I know. At the end of the day If I get stuck I'll also come back here itself. I know how difficult it'll be to find the solution we are looking for. So it'll be my pleasure to help.

Comment: Hey man, How are you? I was wondering if you could help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62580312/react-ant-design-form-items-to-be-split-into-2-columns, since you're the only one who came to my mind cuz of how helpful you were last time when I was really stuck at it haha. Sorry for bothering you also

Comment: Sure. Will have a look and Thanks for reaching out. :)

Comment: I just got it so no worries. Ant Design's library documentation is not the best. Thank you tho! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

I see in redux store you have this:

```
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
// you dont need line below, you exported store and persistore in lines above
export default { store, persistor };
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding `timeout: null` to the persist configuration solved my issue.

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'keyOfStore',
  storage: storage,
  // There is an issue in the source code of redux-persist (default setTimeout does not cleaning)
  timeout: null,
}
const appReducer = combineReducers({
  ...otherReducers,
  keyOfStore: persistReducer(persistConfig, keyOfStoreRedfucer),
})
```

[Got the solution from here](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/786#issuecomment-421850652)