# React Ant Design - Form items to be split into 2 columns

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm new to Ant Design and wanted to split my form items inside of the Form component into 2 columns on my page. I tried with flex-box and it's not working.

There's this "formItemLayout" function as you can see in my code from their documentation but there's not so info for it. I don't know if I can use it to split them

Is there any way to have them split into 2 halves on the page vertically (like into 2 columns, each taking 50% of the page)

Any help would be appreciate.

```
import React from "react";

import { Form, Select, InputNumber, Input, Button, Upload, Space } from "antd";

import { UploadOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const { Option } = Select;

const formItemLayout = {
  labelCol: {
    span: 6,
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    span: 5,
  },
};

const normFile = (e) => {
  console.log("Upload event:", e);

  if (Array.isArray(e)) {
    return e;
  }

  return e && e.fileList;
};

const NewDevicePage = () => {
  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
  };

  return (
<div className="fnew-device-page-wrapper">
        <Form name="new-device-form" {...formItemLayout} onFinish={onFinish} hideRequiredMark >
          <Form.Item
            name={["user", "name"]}
            label="Name"
            rules={[
              {
                required: true,
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item name={["user", "url"]} label="URL">
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item
            name="type"
            label="Type"
            hasFeedback
            rules={[
              {
                required: true,
                message: "Please select the type of your device!",
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Select placeholder="Producer">
              <Option value="producer"> Producer </Option>
              <Option value="consumer"> Consumer </Option>
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item label="Price">
            <Form.Item name="price" noStyle>
              <InputNumber min={0} />
            </Form.Item>
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item label="Min balance">
            <Form.Item name="min-balance" noStyle>
              <InputNumber min={0} />
            </Form.Item>
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item
            name="device-image"
            label="Device image"
            valuePropName="fileList"
            getValueFromEvent={normFile}
            extra="No file selected"
          >
            <Upload name="logo" action="/upload.do" listType="picture">
              <Button>
                <UploadOutlined /> Select file
              </Button>
            </Upload>
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item name={["user", "location"]} label="Location">
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item
            name="network"
            label="Network"
            hasFeedback
            rules={[
              {
                required: true,
                message: "Please select the Network",
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Select placeholder="net1">
              <Option value="net1"> Network 1 </Option>
              <Option value="net2"> Network 2 </Option>
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item label="Minimum amount">
            <Form.Item name="min-offer-amount" noStyle>
              <InputNumber min={0} />
            </Form.Item>
          </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item
            wrapperCol={{
              span: 12,
              offset: 6,
            }}
          >
            <Button shape="round" type="primary" htmlType="submit">
              Add a device
            </Button>

            <Button shape="round" danger>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </div>
);
};

export default NewDevicePage;
```

Answer (score 12):

I have created this [sample app](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-react-6ep0g?file=/src/NewDevicePage.js) with the form component provided in the question. Although this is not well formatted in terms of UX but then it'll help how the form elements can be formatted in 2 columns as per your requirement. Please have a look

I have used `Row`, `Col` provided by `antd` for formatting the form items in 2 columns.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked! If I can give you here any awards I would've done it! Thank you!!

Comment: Haha. Thanks for that :). I'm really glad that it helped as I didn't know about `antd` before.

Comment: Please have a look at this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-beaver-krvkm?file=/src/App.js). `Gauge` chart is not by default available in `chart.js` so for that to work I have added another dependency called `chartjs-gauge`. Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Just so you know, your sample app helped me a-lot, was struggling with alot stuff and your sample app is simple yet powerful!

Comment: Happy to have helped you @user5109293123 :)